# Sort a large dictionary by value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.6.4. I have a large, nested dictionary shared by multiple processes, that could eventually contain over 4 billion keys, and I wish to sort it by value ('total'). The dictionary looks like this.

```
scores = { 'id_1': {'total': 3, 'golf': 1, 'football': 2}, 
           'id_2': {'total': 6, 'basketball': 1, 'football': 3, 'tennis': 2}}
```

The dictionary was created using `Manager.dict()` where each process would update the individual game score and `total`. I'm now testing a much smaller example of the dictionary when all processes have finished writing to it, and am using `sorted()` to sort `total`.

```
sorted_scores = sorted(scores.item(), key = lambda item: item[1]['total'], reverse=True)
```

I believe it might be inefficient to sort a dictionary with 4 billion keys, and so I'm wondering if there is a different way to do this. Eventually, I just want to find the top 100 scores, the corresponding `id_x` and the entry (e.g. `'basketball'`, `'football'`, etc).

I'm open to using a simple database as long as it supports multi-process, or a better way to handle the dictionary.

Comment: Just use a database. If you're storing and retrieving this much data you're best off using a database.

Comment: You could use `nlargest` from [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/heapq.html) to get top 100 scores without sorting all of the values.

Comment: FWIW, if you are only after the top 100, you don't need to sort. Sorting is at a minimum O(n * log(n)), but finding the max you should be able to do in O(n)...still daunting for 4 billion items, but an improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking to find the top 100 keys from a humongous database.  Read in 10,000 records (say) and throw away all but the top 100.  Read in another 10,000 - 100, and then throw away all but the top 100.  Repeat until you've made it through the entire database.  When you're done, you're left with the 100 largest records.

You can also use a heap.  After you've read 100 records into the heap, one at a time add a record to the heap, and then remove the smallest.  Add another then remove the smallest.

Both methods are essentially linear in the number of records times a small constant.  (Actually O(n log k), where there are a total of n records and you want the top k).

== Updated ==

I was unaware of heapq.nlargest and heap.nsmallest.  These appear to do exactly what the caller wants, and probably are implemented exactly as described above.  Better to use an already existing library routine than to roll your own.

Comment: As a further optimisation for the heap approach, before the "add another then remove smallest" step, check if the new item is smaller than the existing smallest element. If it is smaller, there's no need to add it only to remove it again.

Comment: As a small aside, I would guess that the builtin `heapq.nlargest` will probably be faster than an ad hoc implementation. It also accepts an iterable, so there is no need to use a buffer when reading from a database.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem.  You're probably right.  I mistakenly thought that heqp.nlargest worked on an already existing heap, and returned the n largest elements.  I now see I was wrong.  It probably does exactly what I described above.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I tried doing `top_100 = heapq.nlargest(100, scores.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['total'])` and got what I wanted.

Comment: @sabik.  I used to give a question similar to this when I gave interviews.  It the candidate claimed to have a background in probability/statistics, a follow up question would be: How many heap insertions, on average, does the optimization you recommend save.   (And yes, the optimization is worthwhile.)

Comment: Yeah; I know the number of insertions saved can be calculated using known formulas, but I'd have to google them. Possibly the factor ⅟ₑ would be involved somewhere?